# Synthesis for condition with never executing statements

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Will these two code examples have the same synthesis result? Does the result depend on the compiler?

First example, "do something B" will never be executed (specified under clock)

```
localparam a = 0;
always @(posedge CLK) begin
    if (a < 5) 
        // do something A
    else
        // do something B
end
```

Second example: "do something B" will never be executed, but now it is specified under generate block.

```
localparam a = 0;
generate
    if (a < 5) begin
        always @(posedge CLK) begin
            // do something A
        end
    end else begin
        always @(posedge CLK) begin
            // do something B
        end
    end
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any good compiler tool has an optimization called *constant propagation* or  *constant folding* which eliminates the code for unreachable branches when there are expressions that can be completely evaluated as part of the compilation process. Using the `generate` construct shows your intent and is a guarantee that only one branch will be taken, however it involves more code.

So, yes, they should produce the same synthesis result.